# How can process doing "vfork without exec" end up in a long uninterruptible sleep?

Tags: linux, process, vfork

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988/really-killing-a-process-in-windows) user suggests that

> Normally, Uninterruptible sleep should not last long, but as under windows, broken drivers or broken userpace programs (vfork without exec) can end up sleeping in D forever.

How can userspace program really lock up in D on non-buggy kernel? I though it's sort of little vulnerability for usermode to be able to stuck in D on purpose...

Comment: I know it about FUSE program being able to take it's users to D, but I consider that a drawback of FUSE kernel driver, not FUSE filesystems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a process calls `vfork`, the parent remains in state D as long as the child hasn't executed `_exit` or `execve` (the only two authorized functions, together with `execve`'s relatives like `execvp`, etc.). The parent is still executing the `vfork` call, so it's in state D.

If the child does something like this (which is stupid, but valid), the parent will remain in state D indefinitely, while the child will remain in state R indefinitely.

```
if (!vfork()) while (1) {}
```

Comment: `man vfork` -> `vfork - create a child process and block parent`. OK, now I see. I though was "fork, but preserve *V*irtual memory unified". Parent is locked, but there's a "key" to unlock it, so no problem.