# What was the benefit in not copying page table entries in vfork() system call?

Tags: linux-kernel, vfork

*The vfork () system call has the same effect as fork(), except that the page table entries of the parent process are not copied.Today, with copy-on-write and child-runs-first semantics,the only benefit to vfork() is not copying the page table entries.If Linux one day gains copy-on-write page table entries,there will no longer be any benefit.*

These are some lines from Robert Love's book on 'Linux Kernel Development'.What I don't understand is what is the benefit of not copying the page table entries?

There is also a line which says,"*In copy_process(),the task_struct member vfork_done is set to NULL*".

What is this **vfork_done**? What is its function?

Comment: This overlaps https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5337/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84101/ , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156329/ .

Answer (score 1):

The benefit is simply performance. Copying page table entries requires memory for these page tables, and requires CPU time to perform the copy.